# Argument type cannot be assigned to the parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart

EDIT: Answered by Franken Frank helo, thank you.

Im trying to send a struct to a StatefulWidget, but I'm getting the error

```
"code": "argument_type_not_assignable",
    "message": "The argument type 'RepData' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RepScreen'.",
    
Error Line:
_RepScreenState createState() => _RepScreenState(product);


The struct is RepData, and my StatefulWidget is RepScreen.

class RepScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final RepData product;
  RepScreen(this.product);

  @override
  _RepScreenState createState() => _RepScreenState(product);
}

class _RepScreenState extends State<RepScreen> {

  final RepScreen product;
  _RepScreenState(this.product);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(   
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Struct:

```
class RepData {

  String category;
  String id;
  String title;
  String text;
  List image;
  double long;
  double lat;
  String link;

  RepData.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    id = snapshot.documentID;
    title = snapshot.data['title'];
    text = snapshot.data['text'];
    image = snapshot.data['image'];
    long = snapshot.data['long'];
    lat = snapshot.data['lat'];
    link = snapshot.data['link'];
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your _RepScreenState's constructor takes RepScreen but you pass in a RepData in your createState()